# What does it mean when a table is listed in the join section without a specific join clause?

Tags: t-sql

I was given a query to a database that I'm unfamiliar with and am having trouble figuring out the syntax. I've never seen a table listed like this, so I'd like an explanation of what this is doing:

```
select *
from source_table as source
inner join other_table as other
    on (source.field1 = other.field2),
third_table as third
where source.id = 5
and third.description = 'Overload'
```

How is table `third` being included here? I don't see a join clause for it or a statement for it after `where`.

I've tried setting up a similar query on a database that I'm familiar with, but haven't been able to write a query like this. The query above works, as I've been able to run it, but I'm stumped as to *how* it works. Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: The key is the `,` (comma) following the join to `other_table`. This is the pre-1992 join syntax. That is, its **30 years old** and should be avoided. If you see this, be suspicious of the quality of the code.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, looks like this is just doing a cross join